# Creating nested matrix using random integers

Tags: matrix, random

How do i create 15x2 matrix with 2x2 random integer elements?

My code only returned identical 2x2 elements:
[image: This is what i get when i tried to do that.]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, but post code as text with markdown formatting.

Comment: want to Create 2*2 matrix consist of 2  rows and 15 columns with random integers up to 15.

Comment: Not a 15x2 matrix with each element being a 2x2 random integer matrix? That is what your example looks like.

Comment: That is right..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really want to use `ConstantArray` which always populates the matrix with its first argument repeated as many times as necessary. That first argument is only evaluated once which explains your result. To get what you want, use `RandomInteger` directly. It can build matrices.

```
SeedRandom@42;
RandomInteger[14, {2, 15, 2, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

Answer (score 0):

An inferior alternative to the direct call to `RandomInteger`, but quite close to your original idea:

```
Table[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {2, 2}], {2}, {15}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is good.. Thanks

Comment: Please note that @m_goldbergs answers is the way to go in terms of efficiency and speed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

`Table[MatrixForm[RandomInteger[14, {2, 2}]], {i, 2}, {j,15}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: Thanks... Now how can i find the determinant of this matrix..

Comment: Further calculations with nested `MatrixForm` elements will be difficult, though.